# merge, average and group multiple csv by columns using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have multiple csv files to work on, around 20ish of them, here I put examples of them

blink.csv

`acc  mat   time  win   kill deth ast  xp  gold  hero  leag opp  team
 10  4286   123 FALSE    4    4   2   443   414  96    Fr   Nb   Wg
 10  7329   133 FALSE    3    5   5   409   552  58    Fr   Nb   Wg
 10  5557   144  TRUE    8    7   16  630   770  16    Fr   FT   Wg
 10  7149   145  TRUE    7    3   7   602   601  15    Fr   FT   Wg
 10  1034   148  TRUE    9    0   10  535   580  119   Br   AA   Wg
 10  1861   149  TRUE    0    3   11  426   359  46    Br   AA   Wg`

faithbian.csv

`acc  mat   time  win   kill deth ast  xp  gold  hero  leag opp  team
 13  4286   123 FALSE    1    5   11  455   592  22    Fr   Nb   Wg
 13  7329   133 FALSE    2    7   2   422   159  55    Fr   Nb   Wg
 13  5557   144  TRUE    6    1   12  145   195  99   Fr    FT   Wg
 13  7149   145  TRUE    5    2   1   793   952  5     Fr   FT   Wg
 13  1861   149  TRUE    2    1   12  693   102  11    Br   AA   Wg`

iceice.csv

`acc  mat   time  win   kill deth ast  xp  gold  hero  leag opp  team
 22  7329   133 FALSE    4    2   22  422   259  15    Fr   Nb   Wg
 22  5557   144  TRUE    6    0   2   145   295  212   Fr   FT   Wg
 22  7149   145  TRUE    1    1   1   793   252  2     Fr   FT   Wg
 22  1034   148  TRUE    1    6   1   204   295  56    Br   AA   Wg
 22  1861   149  TRUE    1    11  12  693   202  21    Br   AA   Wg`

What I had in mind is to merge "acc" and "hero" together, sort out by "mat" and also averaging the column "kill, deth, ast, xp, and gold"
This is the output I had in mind

out.csv

`acc         mat    time  win   kill deth ast  xp  gold  hero     leag opp  team
 10,13       4286   123 FALSE    2.5 4.5 6.5  434.5 503  96,22     Fr   Nb   Wg
 10,13,22    7329   133 FALSE    3   4.6 9.6  422   323  58,55,15  Fr   Nb   Wg 
 10,13,22    5557   144  TRUE    6.6 2.6 10   ...   ...  16,99,212 Fr   FT   Wg
 10,13,22    7149   145  TRUE    ..  ..  ..   ...   ...  15,5,2    Fr   FT   Wg
 10,22       1034   148  TRUE    ..  ..  ..   ...   ...  119,26,56 Br   AA   Wg 
 10,13,22    1861   149  TRUE    ..  ..  ..   ...   ...  46,11,21  Br   AA   Wg`

I tried on using this code but it didn't give the output I desired..

```
import pandas as pd
blink = pd.read_csv('blink.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
faithbian = pd.read_csv('faithbian.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])
iceice = pd.read_csv('iceice.csv',keep_default_na=False,na_values=[""])

df = pd.concat([blink,faithbian,iceice],axis=0)
con_df = pd.concat([df.groupby(['mat'])['acc','hero'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ','.join(x.astype(str))),df.groupby(['mat'])['kill','deth','ast','xp','gold'].mean()],axis=1)
con_df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

It deleted "leag","opp","team" column and instead of merging "acc" and "hero", it gave "acc,hero" on all the rows in the first column

Anyone can help me achieve the true output desired?
Thanks.

Comment: before posting a solultion. just out of curiosity what *exactly* are you working on? what's this for?

Comment: It's for my final thesis on Dota 2 tournament prediction

Comment: In any kind of analysis having multiple delimited values in a column is not ideal as you must undergo parsing and wrangling just to use values as indicators. Datasets, databases, etc. are best with one atomic value per cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby.agg`

```
agg_dict = {
    'acc': lambda x: "%s" % ','.join(x.astype(str)),
    'hero': lambda x: "%s" % ','.join(x.astype(str)),
    'kill': 'mean',
    'deth': 'mean',
    'ast': 'mean',
    'xp': 'mean',
    'gold': 'mean',
}
agg_df = df.groupby('mat').agg(agg_dict)
```

and then join this with a DataFrame containing the unique `['mat', 'time', 'win', 'leag', 'opp', 'team']` columns

```
mat_df = df[['mat', 'time', 'win', 'leag', 'opp', 'team']].drop_duplicates()

con_df = pd.merge(agg_df, mat_df, left_index=True, right_on='mat').reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: I tried adding 'mat' onto agg_dic `'mat': lambda x: "%s" % ','.join(x.astype(str)),` it gave me this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 're_index'` I tried changing `re_index` to `reindex` but it made all my columns blank, it just leaves the most top row only

Comment: You got the `KeyError` because `mat` became the index of `agg_df`. I fixed the code. The `re_index` was a typo

Comment: Thank you it leaves no errors now, but I get random zeros on 'acc' now, any idea why? e.g. `101,586,543,102,644,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
` (taken from 1st row of my out.csv)